# Jenkins - JUnit result XMLs in Maven build

Tags: maven, junit, jenkins

I have a build for my maven projects in Jenkins. As a part of build process, we have to trigger a external integration testing environment using Shell scripts , which gives back the test results in form of JUNIT result XMLs. I like to know, how we can plug in the results to test results of the build. In builds for freestyle project, there is step like "Publish JUnit test result report", is there any similar way in maven build? if not, how we can use those JUnit results in build?

Comment: Consider moving your build to a free style project and just invoke maven yourself. I find the free style much more flexible and your case is a good example.

Comment: Don't limit yourself from the same beginning. Use free style project as @EldadAK suggested. In such a way you'll solve quite a lot of other issues.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. As you said, i solved this by having a free style build which will be a down stream build after maven build. Well, i went down in this path as this suits my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to add more JUnit test results. Just install the [xUnit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin). This will add a post build action, where you can configure the path to your custom JUnit results.